# How we can use "context" while using expressionValue(with:context:)?

Tags: ios, swift

i got stuck with a func that uses this method. So i know how using expressionValue(with:context:) function, but it is still opaque for me how context participate. maybe someone has easy example?

```
try traversePropertyMappings {
propertyMapping, destinationName in
if let valueExpression = propertyMapping.valueExpression {
let context: NSMutableDictionary = ["source": sInstance]
guard let destinationValue =
  valueExpression.expressionValue(with: sInstance,
                                  context: context) else {
newAttachment.setValue(destinationValue,
}
 } }
```

Answer (score 1):

The context is used to bind variables to values for the evaluation.
Here is a self-contained example:

```
let context: NSMutableDictionary = ["a": 4.0, "b": 5.0]
let expr = NSExpression(format: "$a + 2 * $b")
if let result = expr.expressionValue(with: nil, context: context) as? Double {
    print(result) // 14.0
}
```

In your code, `valueExpression` contains a "$source" variable which
is bound to the value `sInstance` when evaluating the expression.

Comment: sorry but then why do we need "with object" parameter? In other examples exactly "with object" parameter made this work.

Comment: let myInt = 4
let myFormulaInt = "5 + 4 + myInt * 5"
let intElements = ["myInt": myInt]

let myResultInt = NSExpression(format: myFormulaInt).expressionValueWithObject(intElements, context: nil).integerValue

println(myResultInt)   // 29

Comment: i am really confused sorry(

Comment: What does `print(valueExpression)` show in your above example?

Comment: $source.dateCreated

Comment: @N.Khasanov: Then "$source" will be substituted by `sInstance` and the expression evaluates to `sInstance.dateCreated`.

Comment: but why do we need context?

Comment: @N.Khasanov: I assume that your code is about a Core Data migration. Then the expressions are created from the (fixed) migration model, but you have to substitute some values at runtime.

Comment: yes you re right, and i understand, but it still opaque when should we use this context in more simple examples(